# upgrading php 7 in lamp

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have lamp server installed in ubuntu OS. And, when I check my php version using `phpinfo()` function using php file over web browser it shows PHP Version as 5.5.6 and when I check through terminal window using `php -v` it shows, following message:

> PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4 (cli)  Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

So, I need to know which is my current php version and which version is running in my lamp server.

Comment: Restart Apache and see what phpinfo() says then. `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: This is a better question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: To answer 2 of them, they are both your PHP versions, you have 2 SAPIs installed, the web one (probably mod_php or PHP-FPM) and the CLI. Both can run on their own versions. Since you mention this is for a dev env, I'd suggest looking at Vagrant and / or Docker to make this easier.

Comment: Or maybe [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: tan q guyzzz...